# Upgrading IPython3 to version 5.3.0

Tags: python3, pip, ipython

I've got both IPython and IPython3 installed.  I recently upgraded IPython to version 5.3.0 using pip.  However, I can't figure out how to upgrade IPython3.  It's currently at version 2.4.1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `pip3` to do it:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
pip3 install --upgrade pip --user
pip3 install --upgrade ipython --user
```

Available versions are: 5.4.1, 6.1.0

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipython